# Getting Textvalues on other Page

Tags: flutter, dart, text

im trying to put the Textvalue, i have created via Texteditingcontroller into the text on the Neuigkeiten Page via controller.value, so the texteditingvalue gets displayed on the other page, but my texteditingcontroller do not get recognised in the neugkeitenpage and i cant edit anything there at all.

class InformationContentDetails extends StatefulWidget {
const InformationContentDetails({Key key}) : super(key: key);

```
      @override
    
      State<InformationContentDetails> createState() => _InformationContentDetails();
    }
    class _InformationContentDetails extends State<InformationContentDetails> {
      bool isEnable = false;
      var _controller = new TextEditingController(text: 'Allgemeine Informationen');
      var _controller2 = TextEditingController();
    
      String  name = "Allgemeine Informationen";
      String name2 = "Herzlich Willkommen ...";
    
      textlistener(){
        print("Update: ${_controller.text}");
        print("Update: ${_controller2.text}");
    
      }
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // Start listening to changes
        _controller.addListener(textlistener);
        _controller2.addListener(textlistener);
      }
    
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ResponsiveBuilder(
          builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
            var textAlignment;
            if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop) {
              textAlignment = TextAlign.left;
            } else {
              textAlignment = TextAlign.center;
            }
    
            return Container(
              width: 650,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "${_controller.text}",
                    style: titleTextStyle(sizingInformation.deviceScreenType),
                    textAlign: textAlignment,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    enabled: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    hintText: "Informationen aktualisieren",
                    ),
                    controller : _controller,
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('bearbeiten'),
                    onPressed:(){
                      setState((){
                        name = _controller.text;
                        isEnable = !isEnable;
    
                      });
                    },
    
                  ),
                  Text(
                    name2,
                    style: descriptionTextStyle(sizingInformation.deviceScreenType),
                    textAlign: textAlignment,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: "Informationstext aktualisieren"
                      ),
                      controller : _controller2,
    
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text('bearbeiten'),
                      onPressed:(){
                        setState((){
                          name2 = _controller2.text;
                          isEnable = !isEnable;
    
                        });
                      },
    
                    ),
                  ),
    
    
                ],
              )),
            );
          },
        );
      }
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _controller.dispose();
        _controller2.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    
    
      }
    }

class NeuigkeitenContentDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const NeuigkeitenContentDetails({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NeuigkeitenContentDetails> createState() => _NeuigkeitenContentDetailsState();
}

class _NeuigkeitenContentDetailsState extends State<NeuigkeitenContentDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) {
        var textAlignment;
        if (sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.desktop) {
          textAlignment = TextAlign.left;
        } else {
          textAlignment = TextAlign.center;
        }

        return Container(
          width: 650,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              Text(
                'Neuigkeiten',
                style: titleTextStyle(sizingInformation.deviceScreenType),
                textAlign: textAlignment,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Text(
                'Herzlich Willkommen',
                style: descriptionTextStyle(sizingInformation.deviceScreenType),
                textAlign: textAlignment,
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you navigating between the pages?
if you are using Navigator to move from the first page to the second , you can send the variable there, as long as you will add the String in the constructor of the second page

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your code what you mean by pages.

How does InformationContentDetails relate to, or interact with, NeuigkeitenContentDetails?

If you are using e.g. named routes you may want to look at e.g. [Pass arguments to a named route](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) and or [Send data to a new screen](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data), if on the other hand you need to send information between different widgets in the widget tree you may need to look at something like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) - allowing you to read-only or watch for change and rebuild subscribed code, or other [state management solutions](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).

Otherwise, if they exist simultaneously in the widget tree and you don't want to use a dedicated state management solution you need to pass the necessary data up-and-down through parameters which can get messy. H.t.h.